# Setting up Keras model with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

This is my first time using python and Keras for machine learning I am used to using MATLAB. Basically I have a parquet that contains the labels as one column and the text as the other column. I take the text and vectorize it using the GloVe embedding so after all of this I am left with 2 columns: vectorized, which has a ndarray with 4000 numbers in each numpy array; and the label column. I am then trying to use this vectorized column as my input into my model, but this is where I run into problems.

```
pd_df.head(1) #pd_df is my dataframe
```

output:

```
    vectorized  label
0   [-0.10767000168561935, 0.11052999645471573, 0....   0
```

I then split my data and convert to ndarrays:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(pd_df, test_size=0.3)

trainLabels = train.as_matrix(columns=['label'])
train = train.as_matrix(columns=['vectorized'])

testLabels = test.as_matrix(columns=['label'])
test = test.as_matrix(columns=['vectorized'])
```

I then check the shape of my data:

```
train.shape
(410750, 1)
```

This is where my lack of knowledge on numpy comes in because this size doesn't make sense to me. It seems like it should be (410750, 4000) because each element is a ndarray of 4000 items.

After this I set up my model:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.metrics import binary_accuracy

inputs = Input(shape=(4000,))

x = Dense(units=2000, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(units=500, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(), loss=binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train, 
          trainLabels, 
          epochs=50,
          batch_size=50)
```

Then I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_13 to have shape (4000,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Like I said I am new to machine learning in the python world so any help would be amazing.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have figured out the answer sorry to have bothered anyone. I will be posting my solution as soon as it has been 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to unpack my array of arrays. The way I chose to do this was:

```
xTrain = np.zeros((train.shape[0], 4000))

i = 0
for vector in train: # train is my numpy array of arrays
    xTrain[i] = vector[0]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your training data has only 1 dimension whereas you specify 4000 dimensions in your input. In addition, you should use an embedding layer if working with pre-trained word embeddings such as GloVe. Check out this Keras blog:
https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html

Comment: Yes I was actually looking at that. I think what the problem is the shape says it's only one dimension, but it is a array of 4000 X 1 arrays so it is actually more than one dimension. I guess I'm trying to figure out how to turn my array of arrays into the correct dimensions like it should be.